# Elementor nav bar and Header not stretching to full size

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm working with elementor on wordpress for the first time and I'm trying to create a sticky header (by that, I mean a header that remains at the same position irrespective of scrolling). I've stretched elementor to full width and made width of the header and nav bar 100% ( I've placed one below the other, and It'll be great if either one works). I've even activated the sticky checkbox in elementor to give them the sticky property.
[image]

As you can see, both the header element and navbar stretch only to some portion of the screen and not the entirety. I've tried setting the width to 100% and the max vw and px but nothing seems to work.
I really hope you can help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, I have excatly the same problem, did you find any solution of this problem ?